Character sums over prime
Let $\chi$ be a quadratic character mod $q$. I am interested in finding the best result for how large $N$  should be such that it is guaranteed that
$$\sum_{p=1}^{N} \chi(p) \log p= o(N).$$
I am aware of Heath-Brown's unpublished note, which, assuming the Burgess bound is optimal, proves that:
\begin{align*}
& \chi(p)=-1 & \text{for} &&  q^{1/4\sqrt{e}}< p< q^{1/4}, \\
& \chi(p)=1 & \text{for} && q^{1/4}< p< q^{1/2\sqrt{e}}.
\end{align*}
But it is not clear to me how large the character sum over primes should be to guarantee cancellation. We may assume there are no Siegel zeros.

I think the precise form of the "no Siegel zeroes" assumption could matter a lot here.

If 'no Siegel zero' means 'no exceptional zero', you have cancellation when $q=N^{o(1)}$. Indeed, this is addressed by Theorem 11.16 of Montgomery-Vaughan and Exercise 11.3.1.1 in page 382.

Both Theorem 11.16 and Exercise 11.3.1.1, in the case of no exceptional zero, boil down to equation (11.26). On GRH you can of course take $N$ to be much smaller.

Is $\sum_{p = 1}^N$ meant to be a sum only over primes?

Regarding the Siegel zero, assume the strong form of it, that $L(s, \chi)$ has no zero on the real line.

I was hoping to see if there are better results than, $N \gg q^{1/\epsilon}$. The sum is over primes.

Re, then does $\sum_{p = 1}^N$ mean the sum over the primes in $[1, N]$, or over the first $N$ primes?
